# error in update parameter codeigniter habdesvalortot = habdesvalortot +parameter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
            $query2 = $this->db->get_where('habdesempleados',array('HabDesMes'=>$this->input->post('Mes') , 'EmplRut'=>$this->input->post('Rut'),'HabDesAno'=>$this->input->post('Ano'), 'HDTipo' =>'H' , 'Imponible' =>'True'  ));
    //  $query2 = $this->db->get();
        if($query2->num_rows() > 0){
            
            //$this->db->set('HabDesValorTot', '`HabDesValorTot`+ 1', FALSE);
            $parametro = 1;
$this->db->set('HabDesValorTot', '`HabDesValorTot` * $parametro', FALSE);
$this->db->update('habdesempleados');
            
            
        }
```

Error UPDATE `habdesempleados` SET HabDesValorTot = `HabDesValorTot` * $parametro

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/novatek/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate **'`HabDesValorTot`** * ' string with **$parametro** variable with the concatenation operator ('.')

Try this

```
$this->db->set('HabDesValorTot', '`HabDesValorTot` * ' . $parametro, FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks work fine   $this->db->set('HabDesValorTot', "`HabDesValorUni` /30*$MovMenDiasNoContratado", FALSE);